# How can i get the outlook search folder deleted event?

Tags: c#, outlook, addin-express

I need to get an event when delete outlook search folder
current i am using below event but its not fire

```
void folders_FolderRemove()
{
    MessageBox.Show("A folder was removed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear how you subscribe to the [Remove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.folders.folderremove?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm310)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv15)%26rd%3Dtrue) event of the Folders class.

Most probably the source object is swiped by the garbage collector. You need to declare it at the global scope (i.e. class level) to make sure it is alive when the folder is removed.